# How to update react testing library screen value when component is rendered based on condition?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, react-testing-library

Since it is recommended to use screen rather than getById in react testing library, I'm changing all the instances of it to screen query selectors. However, there's a certain condition I'm not able to change.

```
const newComponent = render(
<AppContext.Provider value={newState}>
<App />
<AppContext.Provider>,
)

const id = queryByAttribute.bind(null,'id')
const result= getById(newComponent.container,'student-details')
expect(result.textContent).toBe('Suga')
```

I used the Testing playground and it suggested to use getByText, but if I do `screen.getByText(/Suga/i)`, it fails because it considers the screen that rendered initially and not the new component to which I provide different state. How can I achieve this conversion?

Note: In the App.js file, the student-detail is a div with id and className.

Answer (score 1):

```
const newComponent = render(
   <AppContext.Provider value={newState}>
      <App />
   <AppContext.Provider>,
)

expect(newComponent.getByText(/suga/i)).toBeInTheDocument
```